# The binding type(s) 'cosmosDBTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have created the azure function application with Cosmos Trigger by using Visual studio 2022, When ever I debug the application I was getting the error like

The binding type(s) 'cosmosDBTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.

I updated my visual studio up to date and after that also I tried then also it's giving the same error,

the below are the versions which I used for creating function

Azure Function V4
.net 6.0
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB 4.4.1
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version 4.2.0

Thanks For the help in advance

I have updated the visual studio and uninstalled and installed cosmosdb extension

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't reproduce the same issue in my side, so what I can do just share you the detailed steps, and hope it can help you check the issue.

1. [Please try to install Azure Cosmos DB emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp&pivots=api-nosql#install-the-emulator)  [(Download it now](https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-emulator)).
2. Then install it and run it, we can open the site(https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html) to check it like below.

   [image]

   [image]
3. We also need to refer the official doc to [Migrate function apps from Azure Cosmos DB extension version 3.x to version 4.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-cosmos-db-version-3-version-4?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

**And here is the sample code in my side**

[image]

[image]

*Function1.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "mydb",
            containerName: "mycontainer",
            Connection  = "CosmosDBConnectionString",
            LeaseContainerName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<ToDoItem> input,
            ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*local.settings.json*

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "CosmosDBConnectionString": "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="

  }
}
```

*ToDoItem.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    // Customize the model with your own desired properties
    public class ToDoItem
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Others**

[image]